Voting strategy for 3-way race/pick 2
I’m pondering an upcoming race in which 3 candidates are running to fill 2 seats.
Candidate A is disliked but a lock to win due to majority party affiliation.
Candidate B is well-liked but will have an uphill battle due to minority party affiliation.
Candidate C is wildly disliked but from majority party.
B is hoping to edge out C. Is best strategy to vote A and B or B only?

The best strategy for whom? Surely this isn’t just about B's single vote. And what is the voting system?

Are you asking about about how B should pitch her campaign?  I'd say a variation of "don't put all your eggs in the same basket".

Im asking how to advise like-minded voters to vote to give B the best chance at prevailing. Should everyone who desires B’s victory vote for B only or does voting for A and B change any probabilities.
As I said before, voters may cast up to 2 votes in the race for the 2 open seats.

"As I said before, voters may cast up to 2 votes in the race for the 2 open seats." Erm, no, you have not.


Is best strategy to vote A and B or B only?

As a voter who wants B to win, it doesn't matter much. But, as a campaign strategy (for B) promoting both A and B to other people is the best choice. This is because it may sway voters who otherwise might have voted for A and C, or for B and C (in what is no doubt a low information voter dominated election) to vote for A and B instead.
The real goal is to minimize the votes cast for C, since A's election can't be prevented. So, anything you can do to shift votes from C to A helps B.
